# Attach posts based on category and position - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with a wordpress site where posts havn't been attached correctly, visibly it makes sense and all posts are in order but in the database there is no reference of any post connection. There are thousands of posts here, so I'll just show an example of what I'm working with, and what I would like to achieve via an action hook, or function. Or even just an update_post method.

Example list of posts currently

```
Post Title 1 (Category = Folder)
Post Title 2 (Category = Item)
Post Title 3 (Category = Item)
Post Title 4 (Category = Item)
Post Title 5 (Category = Item)
Post Title 6 (Category = Folder)
Post Title 7 (Category = Item)
Post Title 8 (Category = Item)
Post Title 9 (Category = Item)
Post Title 10 (Category = Item)
```

What I would like to achieve is:

Any posts in category 'item' that are below a post in category 'folder' to then become children of the above Folder post, so my posts would become something like this:

```
Post Title 1 (Category = Folder)
- Post Title 2 (Category = Item Post_parent = Post Title 1)
- Post Title 3 (Category = Item Post_parent = Post Title 1)
- Post Title 4 (Category = Item Post_parent = Post Title 1)
- Post Title 5 (Category = Item Post_parent = Post Title 1)

Post Title 6 (Category: Folder)
- Post Title 7 (Category = Item Post_parent = Post Title 6)
- Post Title 8 (Category = Item Post_parent = Post Title 6)
- Post Title 9 (Category = Item Post_parent = Post Title 6)
- Post Title 10 (Category = Item Post_parent = Post Title 6)
```

I'm wondering if someone can just put me on the right track of how I could do this writing a script myself. Something along the lines of:

For each post in category link > that is below a post in category folder > make this post a child of post in folder category above

What I am struggling to reference is the 'that is a below a post'. Could this be referenced by using published post date?

Comment: If these are stored in a database, then category should be a different table, and a foreign key relationship should inform which posts are children of which parents.

Comment: @mquinn thanks, these are stored in the database but there is no relationship at current, I need to put together a script to create my desired output and wondering if anyone can put me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, wordpresss post aren't hierarchical so you might want to eanble hierarchy support so you can see them on the back-end, you can add something like this

```
add_action('registered_post_type', '_enable_post_hierarchy', 10, 2 );
function _enable_post_hierarchy( $post_type ) {

    if ($post_type !== 'post') return;
    global $wp_post_types;
    $wp_post_types['post']->hierarchical = 1;
    add_post_type_support( 'post', 'page-attributes' );

}
```

Regarding about your main concern, you can achieve what you want by;

First;
create custom WP_Query, query all the post (though I think you should implement paging as you have a lot of posts) with ITEM category and make sure the order is the same as what you stated above, I believe its `orderby=date` and `order=DESC`

Then;
After you get the results, loop through each result and do another query, this time, it must only need one result, with the category FOLDER and/or not in category ITEM, and the most important part is that the POST_DATE must be greater than the current item POST_DATE (from your loop ), you can either create custom SQL query or try using WP_Query

the other method is to use `get_adjacent_post` built-in function, this is use on wordpress next and previous post, though this won't work if you have other category than ITEM and FOLDER. check it out https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post

Here's some NOT FULLY tested code I've come up with

First lets try getting the data and displaying the array on the front-end to verify if our new data array is built properly

```
// spit the data to verify the order and hierarchy
add_action('wp_head', function() {
    echo '<pre>', print_r( _check_data_post(), 1), '</pre>';
});

function _check_data_post( $display = 'data' ) {

    // ID of the item category
    $item_id = 29;

    //create query argument
    $args = [
        'post_type'     => 'post',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'orderby'     => 'date',
        'order'       => 'DESC',
        'cat'         => $item_id,

        // lets add some limit not to kill the server
        'post_per_page' => 50,

    ];

    //build new query
    $q = new WP_Query( $args );

    //get all query result
    $posts = $q->get_posts();

    //new data holder
    $data = [];

    // loop through each result
    foreach ($posts as $key => $new_post) {

        // the global $post is needed for get_adjacent_post to work
        global $post;

        // assign each result to $post
        $post = $new_post;

        // get the next post, the parameters is as follows
        // false - must not be only in same terms, meaning its not gonna query in ITEM category only but rather query all category
        // $item_id - exclude the specified ID, we must not include the ITEM category
        // false - (true means previous) NEXT to the current $post which is the current item of our loop, meaning it must have greater date than our current item

        // This will not work if you have categories other then Folder and Item
        // You should write your own custom SQL to be more specific and adjust on your need
        $parent = get_adjacent_post( false, $item_id , false );


        if( $display == 'ids' ) {
            // lets return each post ID with additional "parent" ID
            $data[$key]['id']       = $post->ID;
            $data[$key]['parent']   = $parent->ID;
        } else {

            // Display Title and Category instead of the ID to verify the result
            $data[$key]['cat']      = get_the_category( $post->ID )[0]->name;
            $data[$key]['title']    = $post->post_title;
            $data[$key]['parent']   = [
                'cat'       => get_the_category( $parent->ID )[0]->name,
                'title' => $parent->post_title,
            ];
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Once its verified, we will then loop through each item and update each item with new parent post ID, you can call this function somewhere safe and run only once, its also better to add a bunch of conditional verification and error messages

```
function _update_data_post() {

    // get the all the item, must be IDs only
    $list_items = _check_data_post('ids');

    // loop through each item
    foreach ( $list_items as $items ) {

        //assign item data
        $data = [
            'ID'             => $items['id'],
            'post_parent'   => $items['parent'],
        ];

        //update item with assigning post_parent value
        wp_update_post( $data );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is super close apart from, I'm combining the two steps above into one php file called .sorter.php and this doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Yeah, if i try in a plugin this brakes the page, shows white blank screen and internal server error

Comment: you mention there thousand of post you have, so I guess you have to add additional parameter on ```$args``` like ```post_per_page``` to maybe 100 first and see how fast your server can process with those data, then you can request the update page by page using ```paged```

Comment: mmm, not sure it's that Ive setup test data to only work with 50 posts. One thing I've included the functions in functions.php file then I'm calling them like so: 

<?php _check_data_post( $display = 'data' ); ?>

<?php _update_data_post(); ?>
In my sorter.php file, but either way still getting broken screen, any ideas why? I feel like it could be a syntax error somewhere?

Comment: Also can't access my admin area either when this is added to my functions.php file

Comment: this code ```<?php _check_data_post( $display = 'data' ); ?>``` is wrong, you are not suppose to call a function like that, while ```<?php _update_data_post(); ?>``` shouldn't also be called directly, hook it somewhere, like during your plugin activation, that  will assign post parent to the selected query and will mess up the post if the return data aren't correct, just copy all the code above and put it in 1 file, and try not to modify something until you understand the comments I have added

Comment: Ive added all code above into 1 php file called sorter.php. I run it and get internal server error

Comment: check the code again, I've edited my answer as there's a syntax error, on the variable ```$item_id```,  it was close with a comma like ```$item_id = 29,``` instead of semi-colon ```$item_id = 29;``` again, please verify my code, its not fully tested, there might be other syntax error

Comment: With that change, no internal server error, but post parent isn't being set

Comment: that code isn't design to work that way, you had to make adjustment for your situation, its supposed to be just an example as your reference, you'd have to specify the child post category, you have to specify what are the categories that would be excluded on adjacent query and you have to trigger/run the ```_update_data_post``` function somewhere somehow. seems like you didn't even bother to understand how it shoud work and expecting some results.

Comment: Hi Silver, sorry I should have mentioned, I did make all necessary changes to suit my situation, i didn't just copy and paste. Thanks for your help anyway